# Not able to store an object in window on IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'd like to store an object in `window`. Currently it's working on Chrome, Edge, Firefox but not IE.

My code :

```
(function() {

  'use strict';

  var bottom = Object.create(null);

  bottom = {};
  bottom.tools = {};
  bottom.tools.detectIEEdge = detectIEEdge;

  function detectIEEdge() {
    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent,
        msie, trident, rv;
    msie = ua.indexOf('MSIE ');
    if (msie > 0) {
      return parseInt(ua.substring(msie + 5, ua.indexOf('.', msie)), 10);
    }
    trident = ua.indexOf('Trident/');
    if (trident > 0) {
      rv = ua.indexOf('rv:');
      return parseInt(ua.substring(rv + 3, ua.indexOf('.', rv)), 10);
    }
    return false;
  }

  window.bottom = bottom;

  })();
```

And my code in HTML :

```
<script>
  console.log(window.bottom) // undefined
</script>
```

Comment: Version ? 11 works too.

Comment: Internet Explorer 11.719

Comment: When I made a test it shows the object but when I try to check properties in it shows undefined. Can you please inform us about your overall goal for checking this? It can help us to understand your requirements properly and we can try to provide suggestions for it.

Comment: My main goal is to provide a function to detect if the user is using IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said, "**My main goal is to provide a function to detect if the user is using IE.**"

I suggest you refer an example below that can help you to identify the IE browser and its version.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
  
<head> 
    <title> 
      Detects user uses Internet Explorer 
  </title> 
</head> 
  
<body> 
    <center> 
        <h1 style="color:green">Test Demo</h1> 
        <script> 
            //detects if user uses Internet Explorer 
            //returns version of IE or false, if browser is not IE 
            //Function to detect IE or not 
            function IEdetection() { 
                var ua = window.navigator.userAgent; 
                var msie = ua.indexOf('MSIE '); 
                if (msie > 0) { 
                    // IE 10 or older, return version number 
                    return ('IE ' + parseInt(ua.substring( 
                      msie + 5, ua.indexOf('.', msie)), 10)); 
                } 
                var trident = ua.indexOf('Trident/'); 
                if (trident > 0) { 
                    // IE 11, return version number 
                    var rv = ua.indexOf('rv:'); 
                    return ('IE ' + parseInt(ua.substring( 
                      rv + 3, ua.indexOf('.', rv)), 10)); 
                } 
                // User uses other browser 
                return ('Not IE'); 
            } 
            var result = IEdetection(); 
            document.write(result); 
        </script> 
    </center> 
</body> 
  
</html>
```

Output:

[image]

Reference:

[How to check the user is using Internet Explorer in JavaScript?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-check-the-user-is-using-internet-explorer-in-javascript/)